# Proper way to implement a JavaScript class into VueJS

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, vuejs2

Since my main component of one of my pages is getting a bit large and hard to read I'd like to outsource some of the methods into a frontend controller class.
Here is my test class which is located in a subfolder `controller/SporteventsController.js`

```
export class SporteventsController{
    test(){
        return 'Printing test';
    }
}
```

I'm importing the class into my component as follows:

```
import {SporteventsController} from "./controller/SporteventsController.js";
```

for testing I just output the return value of the method test to the console through a method

```
    methods: {
        testmethod() {
            console.log(SporteventsController.prototype.test());
        }
    },
```

I was trying to find a more proper way online on how to import a standart ES6 class into a vuejs component, but without a satisfactory result.

The way I did it above is almost good, but why do I have to use the prototype and can't just use `SporteventsController.test()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define a class function for `SporteventsController`, you need to use the `static` keyword:

> The `static` keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods
>   aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on
>   the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions
>   to create or clone objects.
>   ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static))

```js
//SporteventsController.js

export default class SporteventsController {
  static test() {
    console.log("test");
  }
}
```

```js
// component

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="testFromController">click</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SporteventsController from "./controller/SporteventsController";

export default {
  methods: {
    testFromController() {
      SporteventsController.test()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: yup, that's the one. That works geeat. I kind of answered this in my comment on alx.lzt 's answer.
Thanks very much